# Response with Clob paramaters on ORDS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I've a post method that response with user data, name, id, etc.

```
{
    "allowed": "SI",
    "id": 2112,
    "name": "Manuela Merlo",
    "age": "23"
}
```

Now, I need add picture information on base 64 over the same response. When the picture is the small size the method work fine.

```
{
    "allowed": "SI",
    "id": 2112,
    "name": "Manuela Merlo",
    "age": "23",
    "picture":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAeAB4AAD/....all base 64 here..." 

}
```

but when the image is long size then  fails with error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

ORDS  not support clob parameters at response, only string and long variable is available for store char data.

[image]

This is the source code of the Post module on ords

```
declare
 l_user     varchar2(100);

begin
l_user    :=:username;
:l_allowed:=pkg_users.validate_user(l_user,:password);
:l_id     :=l_user;
:l_name   :=pkg_users.Get_Name(l_user);
:l_age    :=pkg_users.Get_Age(l_user);
:l_picture:=pkg_users.Get_picture(l_user);
end;
```

I'm not able to create a separete method to reponse on another media type because the client app is not updateable.

Are there any workaourond to responde long size on  Ords?

Comment: How do you generate the JSON?

Comment: I am assigning the values from a query to bound variables.  :l_name:= cust_name; :l_picture:=Get_picture(:id_cust);  GetPicture is a function that return the clob on base64

Comment: That's how you use the parameters of the query, I was asking how do you return the result? Do you just do a "SELECT columns FROM..." and let ORDS converts to JSON or you use "SELECT json_object()/json_array/json_... FROM ..." ?

Comment: ORDS, convert the result of the query to json. I not use Json_object.

Comment: But you try to fill the response yourself, while just defining the service to return a json/item and have the query in the source code, e.g. "select allowed, id, name, age, Get_picture(:id_cust) from userdata where id = :id_cust" will return the JSON you expect.

Comment: I've edited my post and added the code of the ords method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250620/discussion-between-pedro-luque-and-p3consulting).

Answer (score 0):

If you return the CLOB as part of a SELECT clause it will work, but returning it as part of the RESPONSE doesn't work, it's limited to 32K, and this make me think that in that case htp.prn() is used behind the scene. So if the only solution for you to return a RESPONSE because you get the results from a procedure, then you should build the whole JSON yourself and use a function that outputs the CLOB using http.prn() by chunk of 32K max.